# What technology is useful for internet access when storms bring down Cable and FIOS?

Tags: networking

I live in an area where storms often knock down fiber and cablemodem lines. What solutions exist for mission-critical internet connectivity? I don't need it to be very fast (in those emergency times, we'd be sending emails, not streaming video). And ideally 1) it would be something that you pay for as you use it, not for months when it sits unused, 2) it would be portable or at least not need to be mounted high on a roof (standard satellite dish). Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't referenced cell data service. Is there something about that option to cause it to be rejected? Other than not having  the pay-per-use option, Starlink looks promising in the other criteria. There are videos showing it set up on a lawn.

Comment: The problem with cell data is that it goes down from congestion as soon as the cablemodems and FIOS go down and everyone switches to hotspots on their LTE. Starlink on a lawn is a great idea!